# How to stop $destroy of scope during moving in $routeProvider among views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have AngularJS App where I use **$routeProvider**.
When I move among views (**ng-view)** I get a new **scope** for page. So then I want to go back to the previous view, I get a new **scope** instead of previous scope.

How to stop **$destroy** of **scope** during moving in **$routeProvider** among views in AngularJS?

And is it possible to move among views quickly using some cache or smth else?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Views should already be cached. You should use services/factories to persist information - not `$scope`.

Comment: I did it. I save all data in my Service and use templateCache for html. But when I move among views my scope is new. So it takes more time like you make everything anew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No.
Angular doesn't approve to stop $destroy of scope during moving in $routeProvider among views in AngularJS.